# Cooling water tank with no electricity

Tags: water, cooling, water-tank

I’m not an engineer, but I love to explore some home issues from time to time to see how people solve it

I was browsing YouTube for a solution to cool home water tanks in high-temperature environments, and I came  across this solution

https://youtu.be/NGDQdXeZ4oM

They claim this will cool the water tank at night and preserve the temperature during the day without electricity!

I found this data sheet about the solution https://pdf.directindustry.com/pdf/hughes-safety-showers/hughes-zero-power-cooler/15889-929541.html#open2035131

The solution is so simple and doesn’t make any sense to me (the heat exchanger should transfer all sun heat during the day to the tank!)

I want to ask you, as an expert, how is this even possible. What is the logic behind it?

Thanks

Comment: This is arguably offtopic since it's not directly a Home Improvement question... but since folks might want to use this to cool water in an off-grid building, I'm going to answer it rather than voting to close.

Comment: It would be better if there was a text description of the procedure, as if the link ever rots there is no question left. Also, demanding people go offsite to be able to comprehend the actual question doesn't really fit the SE format.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited to [physics.se].

Comment: I think my answer provides the description that the querant couldn't/didn't. However, I second the suggestion to take it to https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I apologize for sharing a link about the solution without posting an explanation about the solution here because the company didn't explain how it technically work, this is why I was asking if it's possible, I posted it in "Home Improvement" because I was thinking if I can use it in my home (I wasn't aware about Physics StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that circulation in this system is powered by convection.

During the day, the heat exchanger does indeed heat up -- but since it's at the top of the system, that hot water doesn't flow into the tank. Each day some heat will diffuse inward through the pipes, and of course some will leak inward past the insulation around the tank, but hopefully that's a relatively small amount.

During the night, the heat exchanger radiates heat to the surroundings, cooling the water it contains. By convection, that water sinks, bringing more hot water from the top of the tank into the heat exchanger. That gets cooled in turn, and the process repeats, eventually bringing down the temperature of the entire tank.

It can only cool to the nighttime ambient temperature, and it doesn't cool very quickly -- but that may be enough to compensate for heat gained during the day. Note that they only claim the water is "tepid", not that this actually produces cold water.

Nice little bit of physics.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, makes sense now

Comment: Nite that the tilt of the heat exchanger helps creat a temperature differential between its high and low side to get flow started.